# Haskell 2d list replacement issue

Tags: haskell

I have a function that replaces a certain item in a 2d List depending on the x and y position that looks like so:

```
makenewlist :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]]
makenewlist matrix@(a,b,c) player x y = case (x,y) of 
(0,0) -> [player, (a)!!1, (a)!!2] : (b) : (c)
(0,1) -> [(a)!!0, player, (a)!!2] : (b) : (c)
(0,2) -> [(a)!!0, (a)!!0, player] : (b) : (c)
(1,0) -> (a) : [player, (b)!!1, (b)!!2] : (c)
(1,1) -> (a) : [(b)!!0, player, (b)!!2] : (c)
(1,2) -> (a) : [(b)!!0, (b)!!0, player] : (c)
(2,0) -> (a) : (b) : [player, (c)!!1, (c)!!2]
(2,1) -> (a) : (b) : [(c)!!0, player, (c)!!2]
(2,2) -> (a) : (b) : [(c)!!0, (c)!!0, player]
(_,_) -> [[]]
```

However, the last three lines of code are failing and giving me an error. This is what it is saying:

```
main.hs:22:25: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int'
* In the expression: player
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `[player, (c) !! 1, (c) !! 2]'
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `(b) : [player, (c) !! 1, (c) !! 2]'
|
22 |   (2,0) -> (a) : (b) : [player, (c)!!1, (c)!!2]
|                         ^^^^^^

main.hs:23:33: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int'
* In the expression: player
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `[(c) !! 0, player, (c) !! 2]'
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `(b) : [(c) !! 0, player, (c) !! 2]'
|
23 |   (2,1) -> (a) : (b) : [(c)!!0, player, (c)!!2]
|                                 ^^^^^^

main.hs:24:41: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int'
* In the expression: player
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `[(c) !! 0, (c) !! 0, player]'
  In the second argument of `(:)', namely
    `(b) : [(c) !! 0, (c) !! 0, player]'
|
24 |   (2,2) -> (a) : (b) : [(c)!!0, (c)!!0, player]
|
```

Comment: Your `matrix` is not a 2d list, it is a 3-tuple (probably of lists).

Comment: Could you please provide a type signature for your function ? Makes it easier to understand the intent. Thanks.

Comment: It should also be noted when I remove the last four lines, the code compiles like normal.

Comment: @GregJames If so, the first argument cannot be a tuple. It has to be a list of some sort.

Answer (score -1):

If you write `x : xs`, then `xs` is the list of remaining elements, not the last element, so you should use an empty list. You can also just work with `[x1, x2]` to construct a list, so:

```
makenewlist :: ([a], [a], [a]) -> a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]
makenewlist matrix@(a,b,c) player x y = case (x,y) of 
  (0,0) -> [[player, a!!1, a!!2], b, c]
  (0,1) -> [[a!!0, player, a!!2], b, c]
  (0,2) -> [[a!!0, a!!0, player], b, c]
  (1,0) -> [a, [player, b!!1, b!!2], c]
  (1,1) -> [a, [b!!0, player, b!!2], c]
  (1,2) -> [a, [b!!0, b!!0, player], c]
  (2,0) -> [a, b, [player, c!!1, c!!2]]
  (2,1) -> [a, b, [c!!0, player, c!!2]]
  (2,2) -> [a, b, [c!!0, c!!0, player]]
  _ -> [a, b, c]
```

But the function is quite strange: it takes a 3-tuple of lists as input, and returns a list of list as output. If this is a list of lists, you should pattern match with:

```
makenewlist :: [[a]] -> a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]
makenewlist matrix@[a,b,c] player x y = case (x,y) of 
  (0,0) -> [[player, a!!1, a!!2], b, c]
  (0,1) -> [[a!!0, player, a!!2], b, c]
  (0,2) -> [[a!!0, a!!0, player], b, c]
  (1,0) -> [a, [player, b!!1, b!!2], c]
  (1,1) -> [a, [b!!0, player, b!!2], c]
  (1,2) -> [a, [b!!0, b!!0, player], c]
  (2,0) -> [a, b, [player, c!!1, c!!2]]
  (2,1) -> [a, b, [c!!0, player, c!!2]]
  (2,2) -> [a, b, [c!!0, c!!0, player]]
  _ -> [a, b, c]
```

Furthermore this is too complicated, you can make a simple function that works for a simple row, and one that works for the three rows, so:

```
makenewlist :: [[a]] -> a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]]
makenewlist [a, b, c] v i j
    | i == 0 = [go a, b, c]
    | i == 1 = [a, go b, c]
    | i == 2 = [a, b, go c]
    | otherwise = [a, b, c]
    where go [v0, v1, v2]
              | j == 0 = [v, v1, v2]
              | j == 1 = [v0, v, v2]
              | j == 2 = [v0, v1, v]
              | otherwise = [v0, v1, v2]
```

If it is guaranteed that this is a 3×3-matrix, it is better to work with a 3-tuple of 3-tuples, so `((a, a, a), (a, a, a), (a, a, a))`, then you thus can implement this as:

```
makenewlist :: ((a, a, a), (a, a, a), (a, a, a)) -> a -> Int -> Int -> ((a, a, a), (a, a, a), (a, a, a))
makenewlist (a, b, c) v i j
    | i == 0 = (go a, b, c)
    | i == 1 = (a, go b, c)
    | i == 2 = (a, b, go c)
    | otherwise = (a, b, c)
    where go (v0, v1, v2)
              | j == 0 = (v, v1, v2)
              | j == 1 = (v0, v, v2)
              | j == 2 = (v0, v1, v)
              | otherwise = (v0, v1, v2)
```

We can further generalize this with a utility function that performs a mapping on one of the elements, so:

```
helper :: (a -> a) -> Int -> (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a)
helper f 0 (a, b, c) = (f a, b, c)
helper f 1 (a, b, c) = (a, f b, c)
helper f 2 (a, b, c) = (a, b, f c)
helper f _ (a, b, c) = (a, b, c)
```

then `makenewlist` (probably a better name is `makenewmatrix`) can be implemented as:

```
makenewlist :: ((a, a, a), (a, a, a), (a, a, a)) -> a -> Int -> Int -> ((a, a, a), (a, a, a), (a, a, a))
makenewlist matrix v i j = helper (helper (const v) j) i matrix
```